# CSS div float - top to buttom and left to right

Tags: css, css-float

how can i put the div's from top to buttom and left to right

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxGW/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxGW/2/[image]

**SOLUTION**
http://jsfiddle.net/pMbtk/33/

Comment: does left to right and then top to bottom workout for you??

Comment: no :/ ... i need the order from top to bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `column-count` property for this type of function:

Check my previous answers for this

[I want to show list items as 2 or more columns (dynamic alignment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092830/i-want-to-show-list-items-as-2-or-more-columns-dynamic-alignment/8092856#8092856)

Comment: my contentDiv has an specify height and the message's has a dynamic height (sometimes only one word ... sometimes a text with 10 words). EDIT: ok, it works. Realy nice solution! thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/pMbtk/33/

Answer (score 0):

```
.message {

 width:90px;
 margin:3px;
 background-color:#dfdfdf;
 float : left;
}
```

Try this if left to right and top to bottom works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In this case you have to take column div(s) (red colored in image) and you have to put other divs 1,2,3,4 inside this div... as in image
[image: arrangement]
give below properties to div.

> .message,.outer_div{
>   float:left;
>   height:auto;
>  
>   width:200px;
>  }

**2)** in another case,
if you want from left to right,top to bottom, then you don't need to have a outer div...specified in red color

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
ul {
    width:60px; height: 60px;
}

ul li{
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    list-style:none;
}
ul, ul li {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
   /* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-3.061616997868383e-16, M12=1, M21=1, M22=3.061616997868383e-16, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

   /* IE6 and 7 */ 
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
            M11=-3.061616997868383e-16,
            M12=1,
            M21=1,
            M22=3.061616997868383e-16,
            SizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

untested in IE http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/Y5ZvA/3/
​

Answer (score -1):

Remove height from contentDiv and put `float:left;` so that it wraps your content.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxGW/5/

Comment: That's just not what he asked for, is it?

Comment: the height is important (cant't change it) and when i add the float:left the order (top to bottom) is not correct.

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxGW/10/ hope that will help you show this thing cross browser.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this in your example:

```
.message {

 width:90px;
 margin:3px;
 background-color:#dfdfdf;
 position:absolute;

}
```

and it helps.

Good-Luck !