# How can I style ul li in css?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to show list items as 2 or more columns (dynamic alignment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092830/i-want-to-show-list-items-as-2-or-more-columns-dynamic-alignment)

Sorry for my English!

I have a problem with ul li:

my HTML:

```
<ul>

    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

my css:

```
ul {
width:60px;

}

ul li{
float:left;
width:20px;
list-style:none;
}
```

my list is divided into 3 columns like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

So, my question is: how can I sort my list like :

```
1 4 7 10
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Thanks for any help:D

Comment: I don't think there's css only solution for this.. :s, unless maybe you change your markup a bit?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **css3** `column-count` property for this check this for more

[I want to show list items as 2 or more columns (dynamic alignment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092830/i-want-to-show-list-items-as-2-or-more-columns-dynamic-alignment/8092856#8092856)

Comment: thanks for your answer, css 3 is good , but it may can't not run on IE:D

Comment: there is a javascript for column count property for IE http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/

Answer (score 1):

See fiddle for code and demo

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pGHCd/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pGHCd/embedded/result/

ss:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 to the rescue!

```
ul {
    width:60px; height: 60px;
}

ul li{
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    list-style:none;
}
ul, ul li {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
}
```

​

​

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/Y5ZvA/2/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this on css3 properties as like this

**Css**

```
ul{
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 33%;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 33%;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 33%;
    background:green;
    width:100px;

}
li{
    height:20px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>

    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/pMbtk/376/

But is not work IE