# Order results in 2 columns

Tags: php, css, foreach

I've got an (php) array with, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 results. I want to display them as following in the different situations:

1 result:

```
[result 1]
```

2 results:

```
[result 1]  [result 2]
```

3 results:

```
[result 1]  [result 3]
[result 2]
```

4 results:

```
[result 1]  [result 3]
[result 2]  [result 4]
```

5 results:

```
[result 1]  [result 4]
[result 2]  [result 5]
[result 3]
```

6 results:

```
[result 1]  [result 4]
[result 2]  [result 5]
[result 3]  [result 6]
```

It would be nice if I could this with CSS only (and not with tables of course), so the right order is preserved in the source, but the display goes as above. Otherwise I think I need some weird PHP loop to get these results in the right order on my screen. Anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705323/2-row-element-layout-within-horizontal-div/8705916#8705916 - maybe could help

Comment: see the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022353/how-can-i-style-ul-li-in-css/10022573#10022573

Comment: Show us a sample of your array

Comment: array(
0 => result1
1 => result2
2 => result3
3 => result4
4 => result5
5 => result6)

Answer (score 0):

It guess it's not possible to do something with css only. You will have to split your array in two and display the first half to the first column and the second half to the second column. Should not be very hard to do?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$out = "<table><tbody>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    $el = $array[$i];
    if(($i % 2) === 0){
        $out .= '<tr>';
    }
    $out .= "<td>$el</td>";
    //Handlethe case that this is the last iteration and 
    //the elements of the array are odd
    if((($i % 2) === 1) && (($i + 1) === count($array))){
        $out .= "<td></td></tr>";
    }elseif(($i % 2) === 1){
        $out .= "</tr>";
    }
}

$out .= "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but no tables please :)

Comment: @user468893 you can easyly adapt the code to use divs instead of tr and span instead of td

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 );

$number_of_columns = floatval(2.0); // float to make the below ceil work
$number_of_items = count( $array );
$items_per_column = ceil( $number_of_items / $number_of_columns );
$current_column = 0;

for ( $i = 0; $i < $number_of_items; $i++ ){

    if ( $i % items_per_column == 0 ){ 
        $current_column++;
    }

    echo $i, ' -> ', $current_column, '<br />';
}
```