# Can I make list items look like a stack

Tags: javascript, html, css

Normally, floating HTML elements flow from left to right and falls on the next line if the width of the container reached.

I want to know, if there is any way by which I can make them float in the bottom. I mean the elements should stack upwards on one another.

I think this example would make it clear http://jsfiddle.net/duGVa/

The element falling on the next line, i.e. LI-6, should be on the top of other 5 elements.
and the elements 1-5 should touch to the bottom of the container UL.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: as per i understand may be that's you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092830/i-want-to-show-list-items-as-2-or-more-columns-dynamic-alignment/8092856#8092856

Comment: no no, wait, I ll post an image which will explain it more clearly

Comment: I understand your question, But I think we can't achieve it by simply using css but might be in javascript/jQuery.

Comment: I can think of one solution, which is to add 5 different ULs and add elements in them one by one. but that will require too much processing. 

It would be nice if we can get some better ideas

Answer (score 4):

You can cheat horribly...

use CSS transforms to invert both the UL and the LIs and you'll have the result you want.

```
ul {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #def;
    list-style-type: none;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    filter: flipv();
}

li {
    background: #aaa;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 25px;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    filter: flipv();
}
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNKY3/9) (tested in firefox, chrome)

Comment: Works, but remember to include `-ms-transform` for IE9+, and `transform` for when standards are agreed upon and made standard. Also may want to include `-o-transform` and any others that may exist.

Comment: Wow thanx.. Awesome solution.
Anyways, I don't need to support less than IE8

Comment: Nooooo. its messing up the things.. these elements are in a JQ UI Sortable list, and has a background image of icons. transforming it inverts the icons and dragging the sortable item goes upwards on dragging the mouse down

Comment: @meouw: +1 for good suggestion, Kindly add `filter: flipv();` for IE support also. And kindly Update Demo link with this link: http://jsfiddle.net/bNKY3/9/ It will work on cross browser now.

Comment: @Sven: It will work in IE7- IE8 too by using `filter: flipv();` See my comment.

Comment: @A.K What to do about the draggable problem? the dragging goes in reverse direction..

Comment: Updated to accommodate more browsers as per comments from Kolink and A.K

Answer (score 0):

You have to pragmatically manage to achieve something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>LI 6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>LI 1</li>
    <li>LI 2</li>
    <li>LI 3</li>
    <li>LI 4</li>
    <li>LI 5</li>
</ul>
```

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/duGVa/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Placing your list in a division `<div>` can make it act as a unit.

Then using CSS you can force each list item `<li>` to be centered.

Finally, to make sure each list item `<li>` line up with one another you can set their width to be the same with CSS.

That should appear as a stack. Here is an example..

```
<style type='text/css'>
#stack{
align: left;
}
#stack > ul {
align: center;
}
#stack > ul > li{
align: center;
width: 80px;
border: 2px solid black;
text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

<div id="stack">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Appreciate `meouw` for his good answer mentioned below

**Quoted by `meouw`**

```
/* Only showing mozilla and webkit transforms */
ul {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #def;
    list-style-type: none;
   -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
   -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
}

li {
    background: #aaa;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 25px;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

**But here is the Cross Browser Solution:**

```
/* For All browsers : Chrome. Firefox, Mozilla, IE7+(tested), Opera */

ul {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #def;
    list-style-type: none;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1); /* for Mozilla */
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1); /* for Webkit Safari/Chrome*/
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1); /* for Opera*/
    -ms-transform: scaleY(-1); /* for IE9 + */
    filter: flipv(); /* for IE9 below */
}

li {
    background: #aaa;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 25px;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1); /* for Mozilla */
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1); /* for Webkit Safari/Chrome*/
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1); /* for Opera*/
    -ms-transform: scaleY(-1); /* for IE9 + */
    filter: flipv(); /* for IE9 below */
}
```

For IE 9 Below you may use filter: `flipv();` **[See Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Comment: This solution is acceptable only if it does not mess up the draggable. as I said, JQ draggable is getting reversed. i.e. dragging the mouse in upward direction moves the item towards bottom.

Comment: Yes I saw that, As am I not good in programming logic but might be we can do it with jQuery, See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/bNKY3/55/ it might be helpful

Comment: The "horrible cheat" of meouw is getting even horrifying.. lolzz.. Then I'd stick to the idea of adding the elements in columns and making all columns connected sortable.