# display list item vertically in single ul and multiple columns

Tags: html, css

I need to display the list items vertically and also in multiple columns. But have to use only single `ul`. How could it be possible. Please suggest me.

The output should look like

```
a  e  i
b  f  j
c  g
d  h
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to show list items as 2 or more columns (dynamic alignment)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092830/i-want-to-show-list-items-as-2-or-more-columns-dynamic-alignment)

Comment: Hi used to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html this properites column count http://trentwalton.com/2010/07/19/css3-multi-column-layout-column-count/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Afaik the only way to do that is to use `column-count`:

```
ul {
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Note that it only works in modern browsers and requires vendor prefixes (-webkit-column-count etc).

If you use float, inline or inline-block they will render in a different order.