# styling an unordered list

Tags: html, css

i am trying to get an unorder list to appear like this:

[image]

How can this alignment be achieved? thanks for any help!

Comment: should the number of columns change with the width of your window?

Comment: does it go right to left or top to bottom first?

Comment: @AndyRay I think they're ordered lexicographically, so it's top to bottom first.

Comment: it is supposed to be responsive design so the layout should change when it becomes smaller

Comment: it goes left to right at the moment, if it understand the question? "barn,finans, håndverk, kultur, data, forsikring"

Answer (score 2):

For this type of functionality you can use **column-count** property. Write like this:

```
ul{
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
```

For more check this [I want to show list items as 2 or more columns (dynamic alignment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092830/i-want-to-show-list-items-as-2-or-more-columns-dynamic-alignment/8092856#8092856)

*Note: It does not work in IE.*

For IE, you can use this JavaScript: [CSS3 - Multi Column Layout Demonstration](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/)

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work for you :- http://tinkerbin.com/BAzYZaPY

you can you desired result through `column-width`property

The `column-width` property is only supported in Opera.

Firefox supports an alternative, the `-moz-column-width property`.

Safari and Chrome support an alternative, the `-webkit-column-width property`.

Answer (score 0):

or you can try

```
<ul>
<li>cont</li>
<li>cont</li>
<li>cont</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>cont</li>
<li>cont</li>
<li>cont</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>cont</li>
<li>cont</li>
<li>cont</li>
</ul>

ul
{
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this style (below). Number of columns will change dynamically depending on number of elements and available width.

```
<style>
   ul > li
   {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      width: 120px;
   }
</style>
<ul>
    <li>Barn</li>
    <li>Data</li>
    <li>Design</li>
    <li>Lov og rett</li>
    <li>Matt</li>
    <li>Musikk</li>
    <li>Barn</li>
    <li>Data</li>
    <li>Design</li>
    <li>Lov og rett</li>
    <li>Matt</li>
    <li>Musikk</li>
    <li>Barn</li>
    <li>Data</li>
    <li>Design</li>
    <li>Lov og rett</li>
    <li>Matt</li>
    <li>Musikk</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to have fixed number of columns set width on ul element (multiply number of columns by the width of list element, e.g. in this case you want 5 columns set width to 600px):

```
ul {
    width: 600px;
}
```